# Where can we ask questions about GNU TeXmacs?

Tags: discussion

We are 2021...

TeX/LaTeX is often imposed on scientists and students, while there are user friendlier alternatives around such as GNU TeXmacs.  It is a shame that TeXmacs does not get more attention, because its typesetting quality is actually superior to TeX/LaTeX, math typing is far more efficient, and it comes with e.g. an integrated picture editor, etc., etc.

But where on Stackexchange are we assumed to ask questions on TeXmacs?
Is Stackexchange some kind of banana-republic where useful software gets censored?

Comment: I've migrated this to meta as it is about the site/network itself

Comment: This is the first I have heard of TeXmacs. If it is so much better than TeX/LaTeX why is there any need to ask questions? --- GOM

Comment: @PeterWilson But first of all, since "TeXmacs is not based on TeX/LaTeX" (cit. their site), why they put a "TeX" in its name?

Comment: @PeterWilson I think presence in stackexchange is important to raise the awareness of the users on possible alternatives. The fact that you haven't heard about TeXmacs is a sign that there is a problem since it is not a bad software. For example: how would you search for editors designed to compose scientific documents and are not based on TeX? Typically an uninitiated user will be directed to "LaTeX systems", therefore I would argue that the LaTeX stackexchange should allow for discussion of alternatives, in lack of a more suitable place.

Comment: @mgubi This site is about (La)TeX and friends. TEXmacs is not based on TeX. It seems to me that what you are suggesting that the site should be open to all questions about typesetting programs, such as those from Adobe, Word, SILE and others. If you think that is important then aim for a new SE site but that is not beholden on this site.

Answer (score 7):

StackExchange sites in general have a defined scope based on community norms, which tend to derive from the range of expertise available. That of course means that lots of things are not on-topic for any of them. With software in general, [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) tends to be the place to go, whilst for more programmatic aspects, the ['main site'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/texmacs) (StackOverflow) is the place to at least try.

---

Other community-based approaches have similar restrictions. For example, I note that [TopAnswers](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=716) say that non-TeX-based tools are off-topic for them.

Comment: I just tried to ask a question there, but apparently I must first be patient for 90 minutes before being allowed to do so.  Nice sense of a community...

Comment: @Gérard I'm not sure what you mean there - I know there are some limits on low-reputation/new users, but I'm not familiar with this restriction. Note that the 'locals' (community moderators, normal users) don't set the rules in that sense - they are part of the backend controlled by the staff.

Comment: I see that https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6189/are-questions-about-texmacs-on-topic?rq=1 covers some of where TeXmacs is on topic

Comment: @Gérard Like I said, I think newer users are deliberately prevented from asking too frequently as this reduces e.g. spam or 'help, I'm stuck and it's urgent' or ... messages

Comment: @Gérard I think the Area51 proposal simply expired: setting up a new site needs a certain amount of 'buy in' from experienced people

Comment: @Gérard I'm really not sure what you mean. This site has a defined scope which broadly relates to Knuth's TeX and systems _directly_ derived from it. That doesn't mean other software is not useful, it means that we don't cover it. MathJaX is the obvious one, but for example Lua programming _even if in LuaTeX_ would be off-topic without being 'rejected'. It's about having a manageable scope, that's all.

Comment: It seems to me that the question _where_ to ask questions about TeXmacs still makes sense.  And you have just proved me that some people put effort into setting up a community for doing so and that all their work got simply destroyed.

Comment: @Gérard You should stop to insult people.  Or do you want that all people connect with your application is your bad behaviour?

Comment: Sorry, but I am extremely upset.  It is not "my" application, but I feel that the application and its users are being disrespected by your "community".  The fact is that LaTeX is being imposed on users by publishers.  The fact is that stackexchange or stackoverflow or whatever has simply destroyed the efforts of those who have politely attempted to build a community for questions about TeXmacs.  You are guilty of a flagrant abuse of power.

Comment: @Gérard The tex.se community has many flaws, but it is not responsible or even connected to any decisions about proposals about other topics on area51!

Comment: Well, then it is the platform that is highly biased.  It does not give any chance to smaller systems.  This means that people are not even aware that alternatives to LaTeX exist.  And some people (like me) might greatly benefit from such knowledge.  I quickly looked at the available information about TeXmacs on stackexchange and a lot of it is incorrect (if not pure disinformation).  And fact is that I was not even allowed to ask a question about TeXmacs!

Comment: @Gérard On the voting: I didn't downvote and I think the meta question is perfectly reasonably. That said - the odd downvote on meta is not something to get exercised over - it shows disagreement from *one* person.

Comment: @Gérard Almost no-one on this site is involved in the 'decision making' side of publishing. My own day-job work is almost always published from Word drafts as that's what's common in my subject area. People here using LaTeX as authors don't get to decide what 'Publisher X' accept, even if they are involved in the backend workflow.

Comment: @Gérard We do have a question about alternatives to LaTeX (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120271/alternatives-to-latex), but at the same time the site focus is TeX-like tools. and the focus of that question is programmatic approaches mainly. For GUIs, there is a long-standing tension across the network - the Emacs and Vim sites, for example, had a lot of push-back as they are 'covered by SuperUser'.

Comment: In my area, all publishers _demand_ LaTeX. Even ArXiv does, although there is absolutely no reason for it. This is frustrating, because of the loss of typesetting quality when converting from TeXmacs to LaTeX. And because of all the LaTeX bugs. I think that LaTeX lovers don't realize the pain that they inflict on others, be it willingly or unwillingly...  Wouldn't it make sense if, from time to time, people who use LaTeX could at least _see_ how things could be done better?

Comment: @Gérard Publishers requirements tend to be about their workflows - in the end, these are driven at least in part by financial considerations (lots of users of one route -> easier to tell everyone to use that route). My understanding of ArXiV is that they require TeX source for LaTeX-derived PDFs, but do accept PDFs from other methods (most obviously Word).

Comment: @Gérard The 'alternatives' question would be a good place to illustrate the advantages you see in Texmacs. I think that you need to bear in mind that TeX/LaTeX are distinctly different from GUIs in terms of approach - my understanding is that Texmacs has a single GUI and is therefore at least to some extend more like LyX or even InDesign, etc.

Comment: @Gérard I'm really not sure what you are aiming for in wider terms. One reason LaTeX is used is historical - many people here will point out that simple weight-of-numbers restricts some change. (I'm on the LaTeX team, and we've decided a completely new LaTeX is not possible as it could never get enough users.) StackExchange isn't a good way to do 'sales'/promotion - the nearest you can get is a 'big list of objective comparisons' approach, such as is seen in the [IDE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides).

Comment: Publishers used to accept hand-written papers and do the typesetting themselves.  They now force people to use software that suits _them_.  Conforming to _their_ demands means a huge loss of time for authors, especially if you are unable (or less able) to use LaTeX.  It is crazy that we have to learn (in 2021) such an old-fashioned thing!

Comment: @Gérard They still do the typesetting themselves, in something like 3B2 usually (XML worksflows and all that) - LaTeX or Word or ... are just input formats that can be 'massaged' into the right internal form

Comment: In reply to your second point, TeXmacs is wysiwyg and thereby indeed different from LyX.  Have you ever seriously tried TeXmacs?  Then you will see that several statements on the 'alternative' question are very approximate.  But since I am not an 'expert', I won't give my opinion...

Comment: Well, Elsevier subcontracts the typesetting to India, whereas Springer simply takes the Pdf produced by LaTeX.  In both cases, they _demand_ authors to comply to their formats and styles though.  So from the authors point of view, this is a big regression.

Comment: In reply to your last point, I assume that I expected Stackexchange/Stackoverflow to be a suitable (and well indexed) place to ask TeXmacs-related questions.

Comment: @Gérard Well, it depends on subject area (I'm a chemist, and _everything_ is typeset by the publishers, I think always in 3B2). However, that doesn't affect what's in-scope for the site - GUIs in general are off-topic other than where there is a direct overlap with TeX (etc.) features.

Comment: @Gérard A suitable place to ask questions is where there are people who can and want answer them.  Such places develop in various ways, sometimes created by enthusiast, sometimes by some company seeing a benefit. If you want one but can't find something suitable built a webpage yourself or find some who does it. And get rid of the idea that you can convince me  to pester publishers not to use LaTeX, I like LaTeX and I don't like wysiwyg, regardless how good it is (and I have some doubts that texmacs can do some of the stuff I do and need with latex, like chessboards and bears).

Comment: @Gérard If your questions will be programming related, give StackOverflow a try. SO even has a tag for texmacs and all the previous questions got answers.

Comment: as @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz says the answer to your question is clearly the pre-existing texmacs tag at stackoverfow.  The fact that texmacs is off topic _here_ shouldn't be a surprise to you as, as you say, texmacs is different to (la)tex.

Comment: Ulrike, Sam, David: I tried stackoverflow yesterday, but my question got refused (non-experts may only ask one question every now and then).  If I have the courage, then I might retry today.  But it is clear that with all the barriers that are in place, it is discouraging for people to "build" anything (you also mentioned the fact that previous work on Area51 simply got destroyed).

Comment: Concerning wysiwyg, I think that people from the LaTeX community are just being very conservative and narrow-minded.  Have (one of) you guys ever seriously tried TeXmacs?  I know that some of you may have suffered from Word.  But that is not a reason to make others suffer from LaTeX.

Comment: @Gérard The area51 proposal did not get destroyed, it failed to meet the requirements

Comment: So where is it then?  I cannot access it.  I would love to see what these people tried.

Comment: @Gérard -- you say "The fact is that LaTeX is being imposed on users by publishers."  The fact is, at least one publisher was forced by users to adopt LaTeX when AMS-TeX (based on plain TeX) was working perfectly well in production.

Comment: @Gérard No one is saying that anyone should be tied to LaTeX - I'm very happy to see a plurality of tools. But _on this site_ the scope is about TeX and relatives - Texmacs is no more 'on topic' than say MathJax or perhaps even InDesign. That's the key here - one needs a manageable, defined scope.

Comment: @Gérard I think only 'higher rep' users on Area51 will be able to see it - I suspect there was simply not enough buy-in from users. I know there are at least a couple of dedicated Texmacs forums, and I suspect users ask questions there. (ConTeXt is a little similar in that one likely gets faster answers on their mailing list than on TeX-sx, even though ConTeXt _is_ on topic.)

Comment: Yes, all publishers in mathematics and most publishers in physics and computer science impose LaTeX (or Word).  Please make me aware of publishers that allow me to use Pdf or a format of my choice (possibly with some style rules).

Comment: @Gérard In the end publishers need to get your text into their systems. Yes, in the past that was hand-written or typped manuscripts, but that's a long time ago now. They are all expecting some format(s) that they can quickly parse, and that means they will limit the possibilities. Even with a limited range of inputs, they have a tendency to mess up some of the conversion in my experience.

Comment: OK Joseph, that sounds like confirmation that stack* is not a suitable place for questions about TeXmacs.  I understand this for the TeX/LaTeX part, but it is disappointing for stackoverflow, area51 (as a non-expert, I am a bit lost, I admit). I'll use the TeXmacs forum for my questions, but I hoped to give them better visibility.

Comment: @Gérard Style guides are not the point - publishers likely want data in XML or similar to generate HTML for webview, possibly with metadata extraction or other 'enrichment' markup. In any case, _we here_ have _no control_ over that - from the point of view of publishers, we are just 'journal fodder'.

Comment: Yes Joseph, publishers created a very author-unfriendly world, especially for those who use TeXmacs.  I might be back on stackexchange for further questions about LaTeX conversions of TeXmacs documents, because LaTeX is often unintelligible for the common mind, its style packages are mutually incompatible, and the software seems full of bugs at any rate...

Comment: Have you looked at the Html that is generated by TeXmacs?  It is much better than with any other Math software...  The publishers are intolerant, but also fools.

Comment: @Gérard Remember we are talking about database-driven delivery - whilst some publishers might use your source 'directly', most will convert it into small marked-up chunks which bear little resemblance to Word, LaTeX, HTML or anything else you might see as output.

Comment: "Concerning wysiwyg, I think that people from the LaTeX community are just being very conservative and narrow-minded." why are you saying this  repeatedly, you really don't know what tools the people here use, it isn't that relevant to the question, texmacs isn't tex so you should not ask here isn't that obvious? If you had difficulties asking at stackoverflow that's a shame but there is no point complaining here about that, complain on the stackoverflow meta, we can't control that at all.

Comment: Well, sorry if my words sound provocative to you, but this is part of the problem.  Newcomers regard people from the LaTeX community as the "experts" on mathematical typesetting and how things "should be done".  Professors force their students to learn LaTeX (without mentioning or knowing about alternatives), etc.  The most influential LaTeX users have an instinctive disgust (or scepticism) for wysiwyg editing tools (often without trying new ones).  So yes, this conservatism (or dogmatism) definitely contributes to the fact that many people are not even aware of the existence of alternatives.

Comment: I understand that a TeX/LaTeX forum is about the promotion of TeX/LaTeX.  But the quasi-absence of any mention of an alternative like TeXmacs indeed reflects a certain narrow-mindedness of this community.  Did any of you guys seriously try TeXmacs?

Comment: @Gérard I have no idea how university lecturers ('professors') can do that - after all, one can still hand-write most submissions, certainly for exams, etc. I use a GUI for chemistry diagrams routinely _despite_ efforts by people to write code-based systems, precisely because it works better.

Comment: @Gérard It's not about 'promotion', it's about 'usage' - 99%+ of the questions on the site are about 'how do I do X', and as I've said, the StackExchange format is _very poor_ at 'what is best' or 'compare these tools' questions. We have a long-standing idea that alternative approaches to solving an issue are 'acceptable' in answers, which means usually ConTeXt or plain TeX for LaTeX questions, PSTricks for TikZ questions, etc., but can mean any tool one likes for some fundamental issue (e.g. river detection). See for example (again) the 'alternatives' question, where we have Patoline, ...

Comment: Yes, but even concerning "usage", things might precisely be easier by thinking out of the box.  For instance, maybe, at least for certain users, it would be more efficient to type something in TeXmacs, and then export it to LaTeX.  One publisher once complimented me that my LaTeX "source code" looked "so good", not realizing that it was generated automatically by TeXmacs...

Comment: @Gérard In which case you'd be quite able to post a valid answer, but the _question_ would not be about Texmacs (you could ask/answer one to set it up, something like 'What GUI tools export high-quality LaTeX').

Comment: Well, I don't have the required "reputation" to post any answer.

Comment: @Gérard Like i said, you could ask a question to set this up - you can always answer your own questions, and indeed you can post both parts at the same time

Comment: That worked.  But now the system forbids me to ask a second question.  Gee, how can things become more hostile!?

Comment: @Gérard Like I said before, it's an anti-spam measure and is part of the setup of the network as a whole. It only applies to low-rep accounts - assuming you get a few upvotes, it will 'disappear'

Comment: Well, it remains difficult to ask questions.  I asked a few as you noted, so as to raise a few challenges for TeX/LaTeX with respect to TeXmacs.  There are more, but I could also stop if my questions are inappropriate.

Comment: The questions you asked on the main site are mostly not really suitable for the stackexchage format as they are not focussed on any issue that can have an answer, they are just opinions stated as facts and inviting a respose.  There are discussion forums where that works, but the stackexchange question/answer model really does not support that kind of discussion or "promotion"

Comment: Well, I was just following a suggestion by Joseph Wright.  I don't see why a general question about page breaking does not make sense for LaTeX and why it got downvoted (probably by you).  Very hostile behaviour.

Comment: @Gérard From earlier comments of yours I feel that you want publishers to accept any kind of input from authors. At one point you implied that you would like to submit handwritten manuscripts and at another you asked for publishers who would accept non (La)TeX generated manuscripts. On the whole I find your comments rude and  obsessive. You complain about hostile behaviour; ever thought that you started that? --- GOM